# How to write data in excel sheet in specific cell using servlet?

Tags: java, excel, servlets

I'm New to Servlet please help me out. I have created a Servlet file in which one excel file contains some data from the user. data is printed through the string. Now, most of the data is printed as per the expectation but now I want to print array stored data in a specific cell of the excel sheet and in a specific format. please refer the provided photo for the format that what I'm expecting. and also refer my code for the more better understanding. the main goal is to print array stored data in the specific cell of excel sheet. Please help me with the code because I'm really new to the Servlets. refer this **[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NiUZI.jpg)**

**testExcel**

```
@WebServlet("/testExcel")
public class testExcel extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    String emails = "xyz@gmail.com";

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(req, resp);
    }

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        OutputStream writer = response.getOutputStream();
//        FileWriter writer =null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        ResultSet rs1 = null;
        Connection con = null;
        ArrayList data_ar = new ArrayList();
        String str = "";
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        PreparedStatement ps1 = null;
        try {
            String fileName = emails + "data.csv";
            System.out.println(fileName);
            ServletContext context = getServletContext();
            String mimeType = context.getMimeType(fileName);
            if (mimeType == null) {
                mimeType = "application/octet-stream";
            }
            response.setContentType(mimeType);
            String headerKey = "Content-Disposition";
            String headerValue = String.format("attachment; filename=\"%s\"", fileName);
            response.setHeader(headerKey, headerValue);
            ConnectionClass cn = new ConnectionClass();
            con = cn.connectDb();

            System.out.println("fileName" + fileName);

            //Write the CSV file header
            CSVUtil.writeLine(writer, Arrays.asList("NAME", "email", "  ", "  ", "  ", "NAME AND EMAIL"));
            ps = con.prepareStatement("select name,email from user");
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            ps1 = con.prepareStatement("select name,email from user");
            rs1 = ps1.executeQuery();

            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println(rs.getString("name"));
                CSVUtil.writeLine(writer, Arrays.asList(rs.getString("name"), rs.getString("email")));
            }
            while (rs1.next()) {
                data_ar.add(rs1.getString("name") + "     " + rs1.getString("email") + "\n");

            }
            str = String.join(" ", data_ar);
            CSVUtil.writeLine(writer, Arrays.asList("  ", "  ", "  ", "  ", "  ", str));
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                rs.close();
                ps.close();
                con.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**csvutil.java**

```
public class CSVUtil {

private static final char DEFAULT_SEPARATOR = ',';

public static void writeLine(OutputStream w, List<String> values) throws IOException {
    writeLine(w, values, DEFAULT_SEPARATOR, ' ');
}

public static void writeLine(OutputStream w, List<String> values, char separators) throws IOException {
    writeLine(w, values, separators, ' ');
}

// https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180
private static String followCVSformat(String value) {

    String result = value;
    if (result.contains("\"")) {
        result = result.replace("\"", "\"\"");
    }
    return result;

}

public static void writeLine(OutputStream w, List<String> values, char separators, char customQuote) throws IOException {

    boolean first = true;

    // default customQuote is empty

    if (separators == ' ') {
        separators = DEFAULT_SEPARATOR;
    }

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (String value : values) {
        if (!first) {
            sb.append(separators);
        }
        if (customQuote == ' ') {
            sb.append(followCVSformat(value));
        } else {
            sb.append(customQuote).append(followCVSformat(value)).append(customQuote);
        }

        first = false;
    }
    sb.append("\n");
    String str = sb.toString();
    byte[] bytes = str.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    w.write(bytes);

}

}
```

Comment: Please clarify what is the issue, what is not as expected.

Comment: issue is the next line of email is get printed on the first column. that's i don't want. thats the main issue

Answer (score -1):

Simple and Quick answer:

You should try to use [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org) :

Maven dependancy :

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
  <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
  <version>3.15</version>
</dependency>
```

Simple class to write a list in excel file :

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ApachePOIExcelWrite {

    private static final String FILE_NAME = "/tmp/MyFirstExcel.xlsx";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Datatypes in Java");
        Object[][] datatypes = {
                {"Datatype", "Type", "Size(in bytes)"},
                {"int", "Primitive", 2},
                {"float", "Primitive", 4},
                {"double", "Primitive", 8},
                {"char", "Primitive", 1},
                {"String", "Non-Primitive", "No fixed size"}
        };

        int rowNum = 0;
        System.out.println("Creating excel");

        for (Object[] datatype : datatypes) {
            Row row = sheet.createRow(rowNum++);
            int colNum = 0;
            for (Object field : datatype) {
                Cell cell = row.createCell(colNum++);
                if (field instanceof String) {
                    cell.setCellValue((String) field);
                } else if (field instanceof Integer) {
                    cell.setCellValue((Integer) field);
                }
            }
        }

        try {
            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(FILE_NAME);
            workbook.write(outputStream);
            workbook.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Done");
    }
}
```

Comment: i'm not using maven in my project. only using servlet

Comment: can you show me servlet code please it will be more helpful for me.

Comment: You can add all jars of apache poi to your class path.
How to add jars to class path from here :https://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/add-apache-poi-jars/

Comment: now i'm using opencsv jar file only and it's printing nice in excel. but now i want to print in a specific format what i have shown to you. please try to show me with servlet example so i can get  real help. i don't want in pure java.